# Finding equation of internal energy in adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, adiabatic

I am doing a review of thermodynamic and I encounter the following question,

> Show that if a single-component system is such that $PV^k$ is constant in an adiabatic process (k is a positive constant) the energy is
> $$
> U = \frac{1}{k-1}PV + Nf(PV^k/N^k)
> $$
> where f is an arbitrary function.
>
> Hint: $PV^k$ must be a function of S, so that ($\partial U/\partial V)_S = g(S)\cdot V^{-k}$, where $g(S)$ is an unspecified function.

So my problem is I can find the first term in the expression of energy above but I can't convince myself that the function of $s$ (entropy per mole) is equivalent to $f(PV^k/N^k)$. And I also don't understand how the hint leads me to the solution. Can anyone elaborate on this question to me with respect to the hint? Thanks.

P.S. This question come from H.Callen's *Thermodynamic and Thermostatistics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the unmentioned assumption here is that the adiabatic process in question is quasistatic/reversible. In this case no heat transfer means no entropy change, $dS=0$, that is
$$
dU=TdS - PdV=PdV
$$

The hint seems only to confuse the matters: indeed, $PV^k=c$ is a constant, hence
$$
dU = -cV^{-k}dV \Rightarrow U = \frac{cV^{1-k}}{k-1}=\frac{PV}{k-1} + C$$
Since $PV^k$ is a constant, the integration constant can be a function of $PV^k$ without loss of generality. The proportionality to $N$ is due to the internal energy being an extensive function.

Comment: The $dU$ expression, to apply in the general case, should have an additional $(\partial U/\partial S)_VdS$ term for cases when the entropy isn't constant. I was hoping that the answer would connect the integral of this term with the $Nf(PV^k/N^k)$ term in the question and also explain why $Nf(PV^k/N^k)$ is necessary instead of the simpler $f(PV^k)$.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I will think about it, but I do not have a ready answer.

Comment: Isn't that because in this case we have a single component system that reduces $U$ to $U(S, V, N)$ and as we know $U$ is a first-order function so that $ U(S, V, N) = NU(S/N, V/N, 1)$ which further reduces to the energy per mole and hence that becomes $u(s, v)$.

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak Indeed, I think this is it. Thanks.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thanks for your comment though. But I want to confirm with you something. That is since the integral gives a constant term and also since $PV^k$ is constant thus it is always possible to use a constant to express another constant. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak Yes, this is what I meant. Note that $N$ is also a constant in an adiabatic process (which means neither heat nor particle exchange).

Comment: @RogerVadim I see thanks for your answer!